# How to guarantee constrained values on a type in Coq?

Tags: coq

If I have something like:

```
Record Version :=
  mkVersion { major:nat; minor:nat; branch:nat; hotfix:nat }.
```

How could I add hard guarantees about values in this type, like:

```
hotfix v > 0 && hotfix v < 8
```

And no one could create a Version with wrong values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add a field for the proof.  To tidy it up, you could wrap `hotfix` in its own type:

```
Record hotfix_t := Hotfix { 
  hf_val : nat; 
  hf_pf : hf_val > 0 /\ hf_val < 8
}.
Record Version := mkVersion {
  major : nat;
  minor : nat;
  branch : nat;
  hotfix : hotfix_t
}.
```

Comment: Hey Arthur, I suggest we don't recommend to people using proof fields in subtypes that are not irrelevant, as that will create them many problems later on, cheers!

Comment: Is it possible to write it in-place, like: hotfix : {h:nat | h>0 /\ h<8}   and is there a difference?

Comment: @ejgallego you are right. I just thought that the explanation would make the answer too technical and hard to understand.

Comment: @The_Ghost Yes, you can do that. The two are largely equivalent, but there are cases where having a dedicated type is more convenient -- for instance, when you want to define a typeclass instance for `hotfix_t` that is different from the corresponding instance for `{x | P x}`.

Comment: Thanks! Is there some difference in proving both?

Comment: @The_Ghost No. The property is the same in both cases

Comment: You are right Arthur, what I do here is to define a `hotfix_wf : nat -> bool` and have it used in the answer, while noting that the property being decidable is actually important. This kind of stuff turns down people but I'm afraid if you wanna use Coq you still need to know that low-level stuff about proof relevance; actually stdlib2 may make things better.